# How do I exit a function that is waiting for more input?

Tags: r, rstudio

I screwed up a `ggplot` function and ran this wonky line all by itself:  `label = as.character(share)+'%"),` -- and then I didn't realize the cursor was showing a `+` instead of `>` so I ran the whole `ggplot` function again and only then noticed that the console was looking for more input.

I did figure out what was wrong (I needed to close the `'` and `"` I had opened) but I couldn't figure out how to just exit the function entirely. I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and every "exit" command I could think of:

```
+ break
+ }
+ }}}
+ end
+ return()
+ exit
+ '"'
+ 
+ '
+ "
```

Is there a right way to break a function that is waiting for more input in the console?

Comment: Hit escape button?

Comment: In the console, on RStudio Version 1.2.5001 and R version 3.6.1, ```break``` works for me. It prints this warning: "Error: no loop for break/next, jumping to top level", then gives a new prompt. But ```escape``` also works, without an error message.

Comment: ESC works. `break` doesn't in RStudio Version 1.2.5033;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try escape -- or the <kbd>ESC</kbd> button.

You may have to repeat it: eg. <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>ESC</kbd>